# Loop wont display text in a form label

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008, loops, label

I am having trouble changing the text in a label. Can someone show me where the problem is?

```
Public Class Form1
   Dim Tracker As Integer = 0
   Dim Questions(10) As String

 Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) 
 Handles MyBase.Load

    Questions(0) = "Are you mad?"
    Questions(1) = "Are you sad?"
    Questions(2) = "Are you glad?"
    Questions(3) = "Are you happy?"
    Questions(4) = "Are you indebted?"
    Questions(5) = "Are you swimming in money?"
    Questions(6) = "Do you play sports?"
    Questions(7) = "Do you watch SportsCenter?"
    Questions(8) = "Do you cheer for the Pistons?"
    Questions(9) = "Do you cheer for the Lions?"


End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) 
Handles Button1.Click
    Button1.Text = "Next"

    For i = 0 To Questions.Length - 1

        Label1.Text += Questions(i)
    Next

End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: What is the output of above code?

Comment: A blank label, when it is supposed to be display the corresponding question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just used the button click to increment a counter variable, and then set that variable to the array index.